# How to change sitecore template of particular item using c# coding?

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore

Anybody knows change how to change sitecore template of particular item using c# coding???

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. _Give me a reference or code snippet_ are not welcome. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: Ok, Sorry for that I will change question.

Comment: The question is clear and concise. In this instance no reference code is required.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually the question is clear enough.

```
var template = Sitecore.Context.Database.Templates["common/folder"];
item.ChangeTemplate( template );
```

I hope this is enough to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Try to use IDs for templates whenever possible.

Comment: What if you need to update multiple items from the template A to the template B?

Comment: Same code, but you would need to build up a loop around it.

Comment: Marks answer is correct but just a little change though, the path of the template should be related to template folder which means it should be "common/folder"

Comment: Fixed the path reference.